# Android VerifyError when catching an abstract exception in Java anonymous class

Tags: java, android, reflection, anonymous-class, verifyerror

I get some strange bug and I would like to understand what happens.

First of all, I am using reflection on fragment objects in Android. To do it, I must catch reflective exceptions.

**THIS CODE WORKS:**

```
try
{
    return (String) MyFragment.class.getMethod("aStaticMethod", new Class[]{MyActivity.class} ).invoke(null, myActivity);
}
catch(NoSuchMethodException e)
{
    return "fail";
}
catch(IllegalAccessException e)
{
    return "fail";
}
catch(InvocationTargetException e)
{
    return "fail";
}
```

But since all the exceptions are subclasses of ReflectiveOperationException, I can just make one exception handler.

**THIS CODE WORKS:**

```
try
{
    return (String) MyFragment.class.getMethod("aStaticMethod", new Class[]{MyActivity.class} ).invoke(null, myActivity);
}
catch(ReflectiveOperationException e)
{
    return "fail";
}
```

This code works when it is a part of a normal Java function. However, things get tricky when I try to use it in an anonymous class.

**THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK:**

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            return (String) MyFragment.class.getMethod("aStaticMethod", new Class[]{MyActivity.class} ).invoke(null, myActivity);
        }
        catch(ReflectiveOperationException e)
        {
            return "fail";
        }
    }
});
```

It compiles smoothly, but I get a VerifyError when the app reaches that line.

However, if I don't use ReflectiveOperationException and resort to concrete types, things work again!

**THIS CODE WORKS AGAIN:**

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            return (String) MyFragment.class.getMethod("aStaticMethod", new Class[]{MyActivity.class} ).invoke(null, myActivity);
        }
        catch(NoSuchMethodException e)
        {
            return "fail";
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            return "fail";
        }
        catch(InvocationTargetException e)
        {
            return "fail";
        }
    }
});
```

My question: what is going on? Is it some kind of bug in Java or Android or am I doing something illegal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReflectiveOperationException` was added in API 19 (KitKat), using it on any device before API 19 will cause a `VerifyError` because the class dose not exist